# Aspnetcore Correlation failed when facebook or google login and Invalid token when confirm email

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I've done migration of my app to aspnetcore and now I do have random issue with validation tokens.
1. Issue is that randomly users receive

> An error was encountered while handling the remote login. Correlation
>   failed.

The problem is that if I go and test it my self it works.

Second problem is that when user receive Email confirmation token and click link from email they will get

> invalid token

so they can't confirm email.

Firstly I thought issue is with UseCookiePolicy but I've disabled it.

Startup.cs

```
namespace Flymark.Online.Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            _env = env;
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Configure SnapshotCollector from application settings
            services.Configure<SnapshotCollectorConfiguration>(
                Configuration.GetSection(nameof(SnapshotCollectorConfiguration)));
            // Add SnapshotCollector telemetry processor.
            services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryProcessorFactory>(sp => new SnapshotCollectorTelemetryProcessorFactory(sp));
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<TelemetryFilter>();
            services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, AppInsightsInitializer>();
            services.AddCors();
            var decompressionOptions = new RequestDecompressionOptions();

            decompressionOptions.UseDefaults();
            services.AddRequestDecompression(decompressionOptions);

            FlymarkAppSettings.Init(Configuration, _env.EnvironmentName);

            var storageUri = new Uri(Configuration.GetValue<string>("Flymark:DataProtectionStorageUrl"));
            //Get a reference to a container to use for the sample code, and create it if it does not exist.
            var container = new CloudBlobClient(storageUri).GetContainerReference("data-protection");
            services.AddDataProtection()
                .SetApplicationName("Flymark.Online")
                .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(container, "data-protection.xml");

            services.AddDetection();
            services.AddAutoMapper();

            services.AddWebMarkupMin(
                    options =>
                    {
                        options.AllowMinificationInDevelopmentEnvironment = true;
                        options.AllowCompressionInDevelopmentEnvironment = true;
                    })
                .AddHtmlMinification(o =>
                {
                    o.ExcludedPages = new List<IUrlMatcher>
                    {
                        new WildcardUrlMatcher("/scripts/*")
                    };
                    o.MinificationSettings.AttributeQuotesRemovalMode = HtmlAttributeQuotesRemovalMode.KeepQuotes;
                    o.MinificationSettings.EmptyTagRenderMode = HtmlEmptyTagRenderMode.NoSlash;
                    o.MinificationSettings.RemoveOptionalEndTags = false;
                })
                .AddXmlMinification()
                .AddHttpCompression();
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax;
            });

            services
                .AddScoped<UserStore<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>, FlymarkContext, int, IdentityUserClaim<int>,
                        IdentityUserRole<int>, IdentityUserLogin<int>, IdentityUserToken<int>, IdentityRoleClaim<int>>,
                    ApplicationUserStore>();
            services.AddScoped<UserManager<ApplicationUser>, FlymarkUserManager>();
            services.AddScoped<RoleManager<IdentityRole<int>>, ApplicationRoleManager>();
            services.AddScoped<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>, ApplicationSignInManager>();
            services
                .AddScoped<RoleStore<IdentityRole<int>, FlymarkContext, int, IdentityUserRole<int>,
                    IdentityRoleClaim<int>>, ApplicationRoleStore>();
            services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>>(
                    o =>
                    {
                        o.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true; 
                    })
                .AddUserStore<ApplicationUserStore>()
                .AddUserManager<FlymarkUserManager>()
                .AddRoleStore<ApplicationRoleStore>()
                .AddRoleManager<ApplicationRoleManager>()
                .AddSignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager>()
                .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<FlymarkClaimsPrincipalFactory>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory, LoggerFactory>(sp =>
                new LoggerFactory(
                    sp.GetRequiredService<IEnumerable<ILoggerProvider>>(),
                    sp.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<LoggerFilterOptions>>()
                )
            );
            services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options => { options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true; });
            services.AddMemoryCache();
            services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, FlymarkEmailSender>();

            services.AddMvc(o =>
                {
                    o.Conventions.Add(new FlymarkAsyncConvention());
                    o.AllowValidatingTopLevelNodes = false;
                    o.AllowEmptyInputInBodyModelBinding = true;
                })
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
                .AddJsonOptions(opt =>
                {
                    opt.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                    opt.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                    var resolver = opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver;
                    if (resolver == null) return;
                    if (resolver is DefaultContractResolver res) res.NamingStrategy = null;
                });
            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                // Default Password settings.
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 20;
            });
            services
                .AddAuthorization(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                            IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)
                        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                        .Build();
                });
            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddExternalAuthProviders(Configuration)
                .AddFlymarkOpenIdConnectServer()
                .AddOAuthValidation(OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This is the key to control how often validation takes place
                options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
            });
            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(config =>
            {
                config.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/LogIn";
                config.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/LogIn";
                config.SlidingExpiration = true;
                config.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = OnRedirectToLoginAsync;
            });
        }
        private Task OnRedirectToLoginAsync(RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions> context)
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.Contains("/api"))
                context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            else
                context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterSource(new AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource());

            //builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            builder.RegisterModule(new FlymarkDalDiModule
            {
                Configuration = Configuration
            });
            builder.RegisterModule(new DbDiModule(FlymarkAppSettings.Instance.DbContextConnection,
                FlymarkAppSettings.Instance.StorageConnectionString));
            builder.RegisterModule<FlymarkWebDiModule>();
        }

        private CultureInfo CreateCulture(string key)
        {
            return new CultureInfo(key)
            {
                NumberFormat = {NumberDecimalSeparator = "."},
                DateTimeFormat = {ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy"}
            };
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,
            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IMapper mapper)
        {
#if DEBUG
            mapper.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
#endif

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
                app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
                {
                    OnPrepareResponse = context =>
                    {
                        context.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");
                        context.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Expires", "-1");
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/Error500");
                app.UseStaticFiles();
            }

            app.UseCors(builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .SetPreflightMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
                    .AllowAnyHeader();
            });
            app.UseRequestDecompression();
            app.UseLegacyTokenContentTypeFixMiddleware();
            var supportedCultures = new[]
            {
                CreateCulture("en"),
                CreateCulture("ru"),
                CreateCulture("uk")
            };
            app.UseFlymarkExceptionMiddleware();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app
                .UseAuthentication()
                .UseDomainMiddleware()
                .UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
                {
                    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en"),
                    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
                    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
                })
                .UseWebMarkupMin();

            app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
            {
                await next();

                if (ctx.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !ctx.Response.HasStarted)
                {
                    //Re-execute the request so the user gets the error page
                    var originalPath = ctx.Request.Path.Value;
                    ctx.Items["originalPath"] = originalPath;
                    ctx.Request.Path = "/error/error404";
                    await next();
                }
            });
            app
                .UseMvc(routes =>
                {
                    routes.MapRoute(
                        "areaRoute",
                        "{area:exists}/{controller=Dashboard}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                    routes.MapRoute(
                        "default",
                        "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                });
        }
    }
}
```

I am generating url for email confirmation like this:

```
var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);

var callbackUrl = Url.Page("/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        null,
                        new {userId = user.Id, code = code.ToBase64String()},
                        returnDomainUrl.Scheme,
                        returnDomainUrl.Host);
```

I also thought that it could be an angularjs (I still have it on my page) but its not loaded at /signin-facebook since its handled by middleware.

I think issue is somehwere with dataprotection since I am getting them in login and confirmation email

I also tried to base 64 email token, but it wont help in addition I think that url is encoded automatically by Page.Url

Comment: I use this code for creating callbackUrl and it works fine: `var callbackUrl = Url.Page($"./ConfirmEmail", pageHandler: null, values: new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Scheme);`

Comment: @LazZiya are you deploying to azure? also mine is almost the same only I am forcing to generate for specific domain

Comment: no, I deploy to private host

Comment: @LazZiya I have feeling that issue is somewhere with data protection.

Comment: What does your code to confirm the email look like?

Comment: @MattSchley its basically almost not changed as it was installed from Identity (Just tried to use to/from base 64). But issue is that this is completely random....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after weeks of investigations I found an issue.

When user register I will send email and sms, then user goes and confirm sms, which will trigger update of security stamp. Then later if user click confirm email and it fails because security stamp is not the [same as in a token](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/bfec2c14be1e65f7dd361a43950d4c848ad0cd35/src/Identity/Core/src/DataProtectionTokenProvider.cs)

So moving sending confirmation email after phone number is confirmed. Solved half of my problem.

Comment: I know we are technically not supposed to write thanks messages, but...

Thank you for taking the time to come back and write the solution you found later. I am facing the exact same problem, and now I understand, what is going on. :)

Comment: @Kjensen its vital to share knowledge specifically in cases like that. I am happy that it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the tokens validation failed because the tokens are generated in a domain and being validated in another domain.

In ASP.Net this can be solved by having the same machineKey in both domains web.config files.

For ASP.Net Core you can replace the machineKey as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/compatibility/replacing-machinekey?view=aspnetcore-2.2) so you have the same cryptographic settings in both of domains.

see: [Replace the ASP.NET machineKey in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/compatibility/replacing-machinekey?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Thanks m8 but if you check my startup  cs it has it